# How to link OpenCV using eclipse c++

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, installation, eclipse-cdt

I'm using OpenCV in c++. I need to install OpenCV to eclipse  because I will convert my c++ code into an andriod app. I couldn't find a proper and updated installation guide. Do you have a recommendation ?

So far I extracted OpenCV 2.4.2 to C:\opencv, installed MinGW and Eclipse IDE for c/c++. In properties of a project I created, added "C:\opencv\build\include" into the directories of GCC C++ Compiler and added "C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib" to Libraries/ Library Search Path in the MinGW C++ Linker and added the lib files into  Libraries/ Libraries in the MinGW C++ Linker part as well.

Comment: ...you don't need to "install" opencv into eclipse, you need to install opencv and link it using eclipse. See http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Yeah I couldn't expressed myself clearly you are right..changed the question title